# Getting data from my program into snmpd

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I guess I have missed the obvious, maybe, but I am lost for a good answer.

I am developing a stand alone program that will be running on a Linux (Ubuntu?) embedded PC inside a piece of hardware.  I want it to be the "thing" SNMP talks to.  Well, short of compiling in my own SNMD "daemon" code and persuading Linux to let a general user have access to port 161, I think I'll opt for Net-SNMP's snmpd.  I am open to suggestions for better products to use.  LGPL, BSD, MIT, licenses, please.

I am working separately on the MIB and assigning OIDs, etc.  I know what vars I want to set and get, etc.

I have read and reread the stuff on making an SNMP/snmpd Agent and/or subagent.  Near as I can tell, they are both compiled into snmp or linked to it as a shared library.  Right?

So, how do I get that agent to talk to my sepaprate program running in a separate general user session?  Is there a direct technique to use?  D-Bus?  ppen()?  Named pipes?  Shared memory?  Temp files?  UDP port?  Something better?  Or do I really want to turn my program into a .SO and let snmpd launch it?  I assume at that point I'd be abe to tell snmpd where to call in to me to get/set vars.  Right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "AgentX" protocol is a way for arbitrary applications to supply SNMP services to a running system SNMP daemon. Your application listens on some port other than 161 (typically a library will take care of the details for you), and the system snmpd will forward requests for your OIDs to your subagent. This method doesn't involve linking any code into the *system* snmpd.

Often an easier way is to configure the system snmpd to run a script to get or set data. The script can, if you like, use some other kind of IPC to talk to your application (such as JSON to an HTTP server, for example).